# Subset columns from read.dta() input, and export

Tags: r, import, subset, stata

I want to read a Stata file to R, transform and subset it, and then export it, keeping the value labels that exists in the value.table attribute as value labels in the outputted Stata file.

I am providing a small Stata file from the DHS survey to use as the input and example source file. Download here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rrm66fjerub7xiw/BJIR31FL.zip?dl=0

The code simply reads the Stata file, subsets three of its columns. Then modifies the attributes to match the selected subset of variables, and export.

The problem is that I cannot manage to get the labels from the label.table attribute showing in the exported Stata file. Only the underlying integer values are present.

Any advice? It seems this behavior is not very well documented.

```
install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign)  



statafile <- read.dta("BJIR31FL.DTA", convert.factors=TRUE)


stataattr <- attributes(statafile)

myvars <- c("v104","m2a_1","m14_1")
statafilesub <- statafile[,myvars]

stataattr$names <- attributes(statafile)$names[attributes(statafile)$names %in% myvars]
stataattr$formats <- attributes(statafile)$formats[attributes(statafile)$names %in% myvars]
stataattr$types <- attributes(statafile)$types[attributes(statafile)$names %in% myvars]
stataattr$val.labels <- attributes(statafile)$val.labels[which(attributes(statafile)$names %in% myvars)]
stataattr$var.labels <- attributes(statafile)$var.labels[which(attributes(statafile)$names %in% myvars)]
stataattr$row.names <- attributes(statafile)$row.names
stataattr$label.table <- attributes(statafile)$label.table[myvars]
stataattr$class <- attributes(statafile)$class
stataattr$version <- attributes(statafile)$version
attributes(statafilesub) <- stataattr

write.dta(statafilesub, "D:/statafilesub.dta", convert.factors = "labels")
```

Comment: Have you tried `Stata.file` from the "memisc" package to read and subset more directly?

Comment: Thanks. If one investigates the label.table that holds the value labels, this seems to be correct. However, it is not exported when writing the stata file out. This can be seen if one runs the code `attributes(statafilesub)$label.table`. This will print all the value labels and the corresponding numeric factor values. Strangely, the var.labels attributes is exported to stata, providing labels for all the variables.

Comment: By the way. Importing works great with `Stata.file`, but there is no way of exporting the memisc object to stata. `write.dta` from foreign only takes a `data.frame` as input, and memisc is custom designed, and hence not supported.

Comment: One might use `as.data.frame(memisc.df)`and this will maintain some label information as the categorical variables are coerced to factor. In particular, it mainatains the value table, but not the variable labels unfortunately.